# How to merge array multi key to single array

Tags: php

I have a array multi level

```
$array = array("14529" => array("900" => array("87" => array() ) ) );

print_r(array_keys($array)); // result array("14529");
```

How to merge this array to single array

```
$array = array("14529", "900", "87");
```

Comment: did you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234852/how-to-get-all-the-key-in-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: HAve you tried anything?

Comment: Did you forget to set this question as answered?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function that does what you want. It is done recursively, so it doesn't matter how deep the array is.

```
function mergeArrayMultiKeyToSingleArray($array, $result=[])
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = $key;
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result = mergeArrayMultiKeyToSingleArray($value, $result);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

// USAGE:
$array = array("14529" => array("900" => array("87" => array() ) ) );
$array = mergeArrayMultiKeyToSingleArray($array);
// $array is now ["14529", "900", "87"]
```

Comment: beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using [***RecursiveIteratorIterator***](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class:

```
$arr = ["14529" => ["900" => ["87" => [] ] ] ];
$keys = [];
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $k => $v) {
    $keys[] = $k;
}

print_r($keys);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14529
    [1] => 900
    [2] => 87
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using class

```
class ArrayStripper
{
    private $items = [];

    public function strip($arrayOrItem)
    {
        if(is_array($arrayOrItem))
        {
            foreach ($arrayOrItem as $item)
            {
                $this->strip($item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->items[] = $arrayOrItem;
        }
    }

    public function get()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
}
```

---

```
$array = [1 , [2,3] , 4 , [[5 , 6 , 7] , [8 ,9] , 10]];
$stripper = new ArrayStripper();
$stripper->strip($array);
var_dump($stripper->get());
```